# CE 1.8.1 order Item_id find option

Tags: orders, custom-options

For certain cases during adding to cart, I am creating a custom option to the product. As far as I understood this should create a new cart/order item even if the sane product with different values for the custom option is already present.

`productA->customOptionA` and `productA->customOptionB`should appear in separate rows in the cart instead of the latter adding qty on the former.

Now I want to check all my orders if there is an order item with customOptionB.

My first thought was to iterate through the orders, iterate there through the order items and iterate there through the custom options... but isn't there an easier way?

I am stuck in the search for details on order items.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in your database probably.
Check `sales_flat_order_item`, `sales_flat_shipping_item`,`sales_flat_quote_item` `sales_flat_invoice_item` table to see the items from a certain order.